# Invariance under diffeomorphisms of the Hajlasz-Sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234613/invariance-under-diffeomorphisms-of-the-sobolev-hs-spaces) it was shown that if $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ are diffeomorphic non-empty open domains in some Euclidean space then the corresponding local Sobolev spaces are diffeomorphic with diffeomorphism given by the corresponding composition operator
$$
f \mapsto f\circ \phi
,
$$
where $\phi:\Omega\rightarrow \Omega'$ is a diffeomorphism; with the diffeomorphism again being the composition operator?

*The key point here is not the existence of a diffeomorphism between these Banach spaces, which is obvious, but that it is given by the composition operator.*

Let $\mu$ be a measure on a free Carnot group $G$.
I'm wondering, since any free Carnot group $G$ is diffeomorphic to some Euclidean space, then is it true that the Hajlasz-Sobolev space $H_s^p(G;\mu)$ is diffeomorphic to the Hajlasz-Sobolev space $H_s^p(\mathbb{R}^d;\nu)$ where $\nu$ is induced by the (postulated) diffeomorphism?